# OAuth 2.0 + Omniauth with SAP SuccessFactors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, oauth-2.0, saml-2.0

I want to implement an OAuth with SuccessFactors solution for my web application but I am having a hard time figuring out the best way to implement this, or if there is an existing workflow to do this.

I have a Ruby on Rails app that already uses Omniauth to authenticate with other services (Facebook, Twitter, Office 365, etc) so I thought this would be easy.

I just want my users to be able to sign-in using SuccessFactors and to pull basic information from it (name, email, status, etc). I am very unfamiliar with SuccessFactors' method of authentication as detailed [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/03/05/how-to-initiate-an-oauth-connection-to-successfactors-employee-central/). It seems to use both SAML 2.0 and OAuth 2.0.

Does anyone have any experience with this or with similar authentication flows? Will I be able to make this work with Omniauth?

Comment: You can use this https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth-saml or write your own strategy for Oauth2, leveraging part of omniauth and just plugging in the specifics for this provider.